# Calling onStart() on a service while being stopped

Tags: android, service

I have an app in which I'm starting a service when launched:

```
    Intent networkingService=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SocketMngr.class);
    networkingService.putExtra("FbID",myFbId);
    if (mService==null) mService=new Messenger(messageHandler); //mService is private messenger variable of the activity 
    networkingService.putExtra("MESSENGER", mService);
    networkingService.putExtra("REGIDID", regid);
    startService(networkingService);
    bindService(networkingService, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  //mConnection is a private variable of the activity
```

Now, when the user exit the app, I'm setting a static flag variable in my main activity to a value the service will look at every interval seconds to know whether or not to kill himself.

In the main activity:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy()
{
   this.SERVICE_KILL_YOURSELF=true; //this flag is false when app launched
}
```

and in the service, something like:

```
 while(MainActivity.SERVICE_KILL_YOURSELF==false)
 {
    ProcessData(); //can take long time thus can be processed while main activity finished
 }
 stopMySelf()
```

Now, I'm using the depicted scenario because when the user exit the app, the service can still recieve last data packets from a server or sending such data, and only after that, the service should kill himself.

Now, if the service is still processing last data after app destroyed, than app launched again before the service looked at `MainActivity.SERVICE_KILL_YOURSELF`, and then the app sets `SERVICE_KILL_YOURSELF=false` while launching, then `onStart()` will be called and the service won't be stopped, which is fine.

What I'm worried about and question about, is what happens if the service looked at  `MainActivity.SERVICE_KILL_YOURSELF` which is `true` because the app destroyed, then the service beginning to stop itself and while it's being stopped the app launched again and the service's `onStart()` is called.

What will happen in that situation and is there something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on exit  program may not call `onDestroy()` or even `onStop()` you only know that when program exits it will definitely call `onPause()` so be carefull when using `onDestroy()`

Your service may be left as is , even when the user has closed your app.